# Differentiate a numerically defined function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, function-construction, numerics

My function is

```
f[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[(Cos[t] - a)^2 + b^2], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

I want to calculate `g[1,1]` where `g[a,b]` is defined as...

```
g[a_, b_] := Derivative [1, 0][f][a, b]
```

I get the error

> The integrand has evaluated for non-numerical values...

Now I can easily calculate the derivative first and not get an error, but I don't want to do that for a particular reason. I can also use a finite difference formula that I create myself, but I want to use procedures already defined by *Mathematica*.

Is it possible to avoid this error and calculate the derivative of a numerical integral?

Comment: Please, go to the help centre and read more about the markdown and how to properly format your code and format it.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
Clear[f];
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[(Cos[t] - a)^2 + b^2], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

and then add `//N` at the end of the definition of `g[a,b]`

```
g[a_, b_] := Derivative[1, 0][f][a, b]//N
g[1,1]
(*1.80525*)
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution, thank you! What exactly does the //N change here? Does it tell Mathematica to use a different procedure to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Yes. In particular in the documentation it is said "`N[f'[x]]` will give a numerical approximation to a derivative. "  at the end of the Details section.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that 'N[ ]' only converted a result after evaluation, and didn't effect the method of evaluation. I also tried using 'Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]' together with 'ND[f[a,b],a,{1,1}]', but this doesn't work. Do you know why the Mathematica function 'ND[ ]' doesn't do the same thing as Derivative[ ]\\N?

Comment: As far as I understood the syntax of `ND` you should rather use `ND[f[a, 1], a, 1]` which works for me

Comment: Can you show me exactly what you are typing into Mathematica for ND? I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 7):

Just ignore the error message.  Use

```
g[a_, b_] := Quiet@Derivative[1, 0][f][a, b]
(* 1.80525 *)
```

This answer can be verified by

```
(f[1.005, 1] - f[.995, 1])/.01
(* 1.80525 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the function can be evaluated at *complex* arguments, one possibility is to use the [*complex step* derivative approximation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S003614459631241X) of Squire and Trapp.

For this function, it proceeds like so:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[(a - Cos[t])^2 + b^2], {t, 0, Pi}]

(* complex step approximation *)
With[{x = 1, y = 1, h = $MachineEpsilon}, Im[f[x + I h, y]]/h]
   1.80525

(* analytic derivative *)
With[{a = 1, b = 1},
     NIntegrate[(a - Cos[t])/Sqrt[(a - Cos[t])^2 + b^2], {t, 0, Pi}]]
   1.8052526175436538
```

Comment: and you claim not to be a mathematician. Interesting find.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of bbgodfrey's answer that doesn't require quieting:

```
g[a_,b_]:=Activate @ Block[{NIntegrate=Inactive[NIntegrate]},Derivative[1,0][f][a,b]]
```

Check:

```
g[1, 1]
```

> 1.80525

The trick is that Mathematica knows how to take derivatives of inactive integrals, so temporarily inactivating [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) avoids having [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) trying to integrate a symbolic integrand.