# Gradient of a numerically defined eigenvalue function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I want to compute the gradient of a numerically defined, vector argument function using Mathematica's internal functions (One can write one's own function however, then what is the point of having internal functions).

I looked at answers to similar questions,[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102717/derivative-before-numerical-integration) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94323/differentiate-a-numerically-defined-function), however; that didn't help. 
Here is the code I am trying

```
var = {a, b};
f[var_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := var.var;
gradf[var_?VectorQ] := D[f[var], {var}];
gradf[var] /. {a -> .1, b -> .2}
```

The code doesn't return {0.2,0.4} which is the answer, instead it returns un-evaluated symbolic representation of the answer. Any idea what is going on and how to correct this?

Comment: Can you use `f[var_List] := var.var` or `f[var_?VectorQ] := var.var` instead?

Comment: No. If `f[var_?VectorQ] := var.var ` , then the above code works. However, the function I am interested in, is defined numerically (the code presented here is meant for representation purposes, the actual function I want to work with is not var.var. It is a numerical function, I'll spare everyone the actual function unless it is absolutely necessary)

Comment: How is the function derived? Does it come from NDSolve, FindRoot, ...? I think it is always better to utilize the function definition when computing derivatives instead of just relying on the black box output.

Comment: The function `f` takes a list of variables as argument, constructs a matrix, computes its eigen values and applies the $ \sum_i v_i \log v_i $ function to the eigen values $v_i$. It is better to accept numerical values for `f`, since the eigen value computation for large matrices may not yield algebraic results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the comments from the OP above, the problem originates from computing the gradient of a function of the eigenvalues of a non-constant matrix. Below I propose a method for computing this gradient.

*(If there is interest, I could extend this method to also return the variation of the eigenvectors)*

First, I'll assume that we're dealing with real symmetric matrices with no duplicate eigenvalues *(I extend this to all complex matrices at the end)*. Let $M$ be the matrix whose eigenvalues you're computing. Then you can use:

$$\delta \lambda =S.\text{$\delta $M}.S^T$$

to compute the variation in the eigenvalues, where $S$ is the similarity matrix from [`Eigenvectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvectors.html). As a simple example, consider the following matrix:

```
SeedRandom[49];
mat[x_, y_] = (#+Transpose[#])&[
    RandomInteger[10,{3,3}] + 
    RandomInteger[10,{3,3}](RandomChoice[{x,y},{3,3}]^RandomInteger[5,{3,3}])
];
mat[x, y] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  36 & x+14 & 13 \\
>  x+14 & 40 & 3 x^4+10 y^2+4 \\
>  13 & 3 x^4+10 y^2+4 & 20 y+16 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

This example is simple enough that we can compute the exact eigenvalues:

```
eigs = Eigenvalues[mat[x,y]];
```

You're interested in the gradient of $\sum _i^3 \lambda _i \log \left(\lambda _i\right)$, which we can evaluate (at $x=0$, $y=0$) with:

```
D[eigs . Log[eigs], {{x, y}}] /. Thread[{x,y}->0] //N
```

> {0.768965, 71.0006}

Now, lets use the [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) to compute the same result (using N avoids long exact expressions, and also forces [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) to return normalized vectors)

```
{λ, vecs} = Eigensystem @ N[mat[0,0]];
λ
vecs //TeXForm
```

> {55.645,27.0316,9.32339}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -0.675197 & -0.678307 & -0.289842 \\
>  0.560288 & -0.727182 & 0.396589 \\
>  -0.479778 & 0.105381 & 0.871039 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

As a check, we can use the above eigenvectors to regenerate the eigenvalues:

```
λ == Tr[vecs . mat[0, 0] . Transpose[vecs], List]
```

> True

The variation of the eigenvalues with respect to `x` and `y` is given by:

```
δλx = Tr[vecs . Derivative[1,0][mat][0, 0] . Transpose[vecs], List]
δλy = Tr[vecs . Derivative[0,1][mat][0, 0] . Transpose[vecs], List]
```

> {0.915982, -0.814863, -0.101119}
>
> {1.68017, 3.14566, 15.1742}

Since the variation of the $\lambda  \log (\lambda )$ is given by $(1 + \log (\lambda )) \delta \lambda$ we can reproduce our earlier results with:

```
(1 + Log[λ]) . δλx
(1 + Log[λ]) . δλy
```

> 0.768965
>
> 71.0006

Note that this method doesn't explicitly depend on the size of the matrix, so you should be able to apply it to any matrix where [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) is able to return results for a numerical matrix.

Summarizing:

- compute `D[mat[x, y], {{x, y}}]/.{x->x0,y->y0}`
- compute `Eigensystem[mat[x0, y0]]`
- compute $\delta \lambda$ using $\delta \lambda =S.\text{$\delta $M}.S^T$
- compute your trace

---

Here is the extension to all complex matrices. It is more difficult because it requires both the left and right eigenvectors of the matrix. The relevant equation is:

$$\delta \lambda _i = \frac{\overline{l_i}. \delta M .r_i}{\overline{l_i}.r_i}$$

where $r_i$ is the right eigenvector associated with $\lambda _i$, and $\overline{l_i}$ is the complex conjugate of the the left eigenvector. Specifically, $\overline{l_i}$ satisfies:

$$\overline{l_i}.M = \lambda _i  \overline{l_i}$$

or

$$M^{\dagger }. l_i = \bar{\lambda _i} l_i$$

When $M$ is Hermitian, then there is an obvious relationship between these vectors, but when $M$ is not Hermitian, I don't know of such a relationship. Hence, the general case will require 2 [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) calls.

Let's see how this works in practice. Here is a random complex matrix:

```
SeedRandom[42];
mat[x_,y_] = RandomInteger[10,{3,3,2}].{1,I} + 
    RandomInteger[10,{3,3}](RandomChoice[{x,y},{3,3}]^RandomInteger[5,{3,3}]);
mat[x,y] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  5 x^2+6 & 16+2 i & 9 x^5 \\
>  8+6 i & 9 y^2+(4+i) & 8 y+(10+i) \\
>  2 x+8 & 7+10 i & 9 x^5+(3+5 i) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Here is the exact case as a control:

```
eigs=Eigenvalues[mat[x,y]];
D[eigs, {{x, y}}] /. Thread[{x,y}->1.] //Transpose //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  14.179\, +10.2654 i & 12.0111\, -13.4113 i & 28.8099\, +3.14593 i \\
>  6.90469\, -1.59718 i & 1.46593\, +0.158321 i & 9.62938\, +1.43886 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Now, we need to find the eigensystems of `mat[1, 1]` and `ConjugateTranspose @ mat[1,1]`

```
{rλ, rvecs} = Eigensystem[mat[1.,1.]];
{lλ, lvecs} = Eigensystem[ConjugateTranspose @ mat[1.,1.]];
```

It is important that the eigenvalues match, so that the vectors match as well:

```
rλ == Conjugate[lλ]
```

True

The variation of the eigenvalues can then be determined with:

```
Divide[
    Tr[Conjugate@lvecs . Derivative[1,0][mat][1,1] . Transpose[rvecs],List],
    Tr[Conjugate@lvecs . Transpose[rvecs],List]
]
Divide[
    Tr[Conjugate@lvecs . Derivative[0,1][mat][1,1] . Transpose[rvecs],List],
    Tr[Conjugate@lvecs . Transpose[rvecs],List]
]
```

> {28.8099 + 3.14593 I, 14.179 + 10.2654 I, 12.0111 - 13.4113 I}
>
> {9.62938 + 1.43886 I, 6.90469 - 1.59718 I, 1.46593 + 0.158321 I}

This is the same as the control, up to a change in the order of eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works for me!

Comment: @user21455: If you like the answer you can upvote and if this solves your problem, you can press the 'accept answer' button next to it (hint) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
v = {a, b}
gradf[x_, y_] := D[v.v, {v}] /. {a -> x, b -> y}
gradf[0.1, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something using numerical differentiation:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];

ff[{x1_, x2_}] := {x1, x2}.{x1, x2};

nGradf[{a_, b_}] := {ND[ff[{x, b}], x, a], ND[ff[{a, y}], y, b]};

nGradf[{.1, .2}]

(* {0.19999999999999932`,0.4000000000000007`} *)
```